# Is $\frac{(\alpha)^n (\beta)^n} {(\delta)^n} > \frac{(\alpha+1)^n (\beta+1)^n} {(\delta+1)^n}$ for any $n$ ?(in this specific case)

Tags: special-functions, factorial, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

Let $\alpha=(K-1)a$, $\beta=K$ and $\delta=Ka$, where $K>a\ge 1$ ($\delta>\alpha>\beta$).

Can we claim that $\frac{(\alpha)^n (\beta)^n} {(\delta)^n} > \frac{(\alpha+1)^n (\beta+1)^n} {(\delta+1)^n}$ for any $n$ ? In other words : is $ _2F_1(\alpha,\beta,\delta,x) >$ $ _2F_1(\alpha+1,\beta+1,\delta+1,x)$ ?

Here $(.)^n$ is the (rising) Pochhammer symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio of $\frac{(\alpha)^n (\beta)^n} {(\delta)^n}$ to $\frac{(\alpha+1)^n (\beta+1)^n} {(\delta+1)^n}$ is exactly
$$
\frac{\alpha \beta (\delta+n)}{(\alpha+n)(\beta+n)\delta}.
$$
This is less than $1$ precisely when $\alpha \beta (\delta+n) < (\alpha+n)(\beta+n)\delta$, which is equivalent to $\alpha\beta < \delta(n+\alpha+\beta)$. Under the assumptions of the problem, this is always true. Therefore $\frac{(\alpha)^n (\beta)^n} {(\delta)^n} < \frac{(\alpha+1)^n (\beta+1)^n} {(\delta+1)^n}$ always.

Comment: Very good! Could you please help me (if possible) with this [question]   (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067787/analyze-the-variation-of-fx-1-frac1x-k-2f-1k-1a-k-ka-frac1)